# React Native with Redux Form submit form and show loading spinner

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, redux-form

I'm very new to React Native and I'm building my first app with it. As for now I can login to my API using Redux-Form and now I want to add a loading spinner while I'm doing the login process.

For this i'm using this library which makes very easy to add the spiiner [React Native Loading Spinner Overlay](https://github.com/joinspontaneous/react-native-loading-spinner-overlay)

The thing is that when I click on the login button only the spinner shows, the actual login function never executes, if I remove the spinner then the login works.

This is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Form, Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, TextInput, Button, Image } from 'react-native'
import Spinner from 'react-native-loading-spinner-overlay';
import TInput from './TInput'

class LoginScreen extends Component {
    state = {
        loading: false,
    };
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            show: false
        };
    }
    loginEndpointDecider = () => {
        this.setState({show: true})  ;
    }
    showLogin(props){
        let { onLogin, onLogout, onUser, handleSubmit, auth } = props
        if(auth.access_token === '') {
            return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Spinner
                //visibility of Overlay Loading Spinner
                visible={this.state.show}
                //Text with the Spinner
                textContent={'Iniciando Sesión...'}
                //Text style of the Spinner Text
                textStyle={styles.spinnerTextStyle}
                //Animation for the spinner
                animation={"fade"}
                />
                    <Image style={{width: 210, height: 55}} source={require('../resources/images/logo-wallet.png')}
                        />
                    <Field style={styles.input} autoCapitalize="none" placeholder="Cédula o RIF" component={TInput} name={'cedula'} />
                    <Field style={styles.input} autoCapitalize="none" placeholder="Clave" secureTextEntry={true} component={TInput} name={'password'} />
                    <Button
                        title = "Iniciar Sesión"
                        color = "#fab207"
                        style = {{backgroundColor:'#fab207'}}
                        onPress = {() => {
                            this.loginEndpointDecider();
                            handleSubmit(onLogin);
                        }}
                        />
            </View>
            )
        }
        else {
            return (
                <View style={styles.container}>
                    <Text>{auth.email}</Text>
                    <Button title="My Info" color= "#fab207" onPress={()=>onUser(auth)}/>
                    <Text style={{fontWeight:'bold'}}>{auth.name}</Text>
                    <Button title="Logout" color= "#fab207" onPress={()=>onLogout()}/>
                </View>
                )
        }

    }
    render(){
        return this.showLogin(this.props)
   }
}

export default reduxForm({ form: 'login' })(LoginScreen);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex:1,
        justifyContent:'center',
        alignItems:'center'
    },
    input:{
        height:40,
        width:300,
        padding:5,
        borderWidth:0,
        borderBottomWidth:2,
        borderBottomColor:'#fab207',
        borderColor:'#fff',
        margin:10
    },
    spinnerTextStyle: {
        color: '#FFF',
    },
})
```

I've noted that the issue is with the

```
onPress = {() => {
            handleSubmit(onLogin);
          }}
```

If I only do `onPress = { handleSubmit(onLogin)}` then it works

Answer (score 4):

Before I answer your question I want to mention that in you defined state of your component twice. One time as `state={}` and second time within `Constructor` you can keep both of your state parameters `{loading:false, show:false}` as one of them.

Now about your question:

`onPress = { handleSubmit(onLogin)}`

this syntax is completely Ok because you passed `handleSubmit` function as a props and you are using arrow function syntax. You can read more about it here:
https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#why-is-my-function-being-called-every-time-the-component-renders

I give you a simple example to find what is happening here:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View,TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';

class Test extends Component {

    handleSubmit=()=>{
        console.log('I am handleSubmit');
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={this.handleSubmit}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
}

export default Test;
```

Or you can define your `handleSubmit` function as below but it will change your `onPress` :

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View,TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';

class Test extends Component {

    handleSubmit(){
        console.log('I am handleSubmit');
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={()=>this.handleSubmit()}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
}

export default Test;
```

and the third way which is old and is not the syntax of ES6 is binding your function:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View,TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';

class Test extends Component {

    handleSubmit(){
        console.log('I am handleSubmit');
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
}

export default Test;
```

I hope it is helpful. If it worked for you please vote me up:)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Actually none of the solutions works, the handleSubmit is a function of redux-form and I need to execute that along with the spinner, this is for showing the spinner while the function fetch the content from the remote server. The thing is that if I put the handleSubmit function inside an arrow function then it stops working. It's driving me crazy